# Delete data before most recent Sunday - SQL Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to delete all rows from before the most recent Sunday in a view. This can not be hard coded as the data gets updated daily. The only data I have is the date in dd-mm-yyyy format, and I have created a column with Day of Week (Monday being 1, Sunday being 7). Currently using SQL Snowflake, but any idea in any SQL types would be helpful.

TIA.

Comment: Please share sample data, how the desired results should look, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the most recent Sunday by this formula:

```
DATE_TRUNC( 'week', current_date() ) - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```

You do not need to store the day of the week as it can be easily fetched from the date. I think you store the dates in varchar as you said your dates in "dd-mm-yyyy format". I recommend you to store dates in DATE data type.

Here is a sample to delete the data before the most recent Sunday:

```
create or replace table test (mydate VARCHAR, dummy VARCHAR);
insert into test VALUES 
('10-05-2021','willbedeleted'),
('30-10-2021','willbedeleted'),
('31-10-2021','shouldstay'), -- most recent sunday
('01-11-2021','shouldstay'),
('02-11-2021','shouldstay'),
('03-11-2021','shouldstay');

delete from test where TO_DATE( mydate, 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) < 
DATE_TRUNC( 'week', current_date() ) - INTERVAL '1 DAY';

select * from test;

+------------+------------+
|   MYDATE   |   DUMMY    |
+------------+------------+
| 31-10-2021 | shouldstay |
| 01-11-2021 | shouldstay |
| 02-11-2021 | shouldstay |
| 03-11-2021 | shouldstay |
+------------+------------+
```